# List of Service Types for Windows Event ID 7045

Tags: windows, windows-10, services

I'm writing some detection use cases to search for suspicious Windows Services via Windows Event logs, I'm trying to find all of the values for the Service Type field in 7045 events that correspond to the 4697 Service Type flags, however I can't find any definitive documentations on this.

What I mean is, in Event 7045, the Service Type is written out as "kernel mode driver" which correspond to Event 4697's Service Type flag of "0x1". Does anyone know if there's any available online documentations for the rest of the Service Types for 7045?

Answer (score 0):

You will find this information in the
[ServiceType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicetype?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) :

| Adapter | 4 | A service for a hardware device that requires its own driver. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FileSystemDriver | 2 | A file system driver, which is also a Kernel device driver. |
| InteractiveProcess | 256 | A service that can communicate with the desktop. |
| KernelDriver | 1 | A Kernel device driver such as a hard disk or other low-level hardware device driver. |
| RecognizerDriver | 8 | A file system driver used during startup to determine the file systems present on the system. |
| Win32OwnProcess | 16 | A Win32 program that can be started by the Service Controller and that obeys the service control protocol. This type of Win32 service runs in a process by itself. |
| Win32ShareProcess | 32 | A Win32 service that can share a process with other Win32 services. |

Note that this enumeration supports the bitwise combination of its
member values.

Comment: Well, I had referred to this initially, but I realised what was logged in 7045 events are written differently, such as for "Win32OwnProcess" flag is logged as "user mode service".

I was wondering if there's any online documentation on how Windows Event Logger logs the other ServiceTypes.

Comment: That's all I was able to find.